# How to make an Edit Text Scrollable that is wrapped inside another scroll view?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, scrollbar

I have designed a note taking interface in which I have two edit texts one is for title and the other one is for description. I want the description's edit text to take infinite text but whenever I put long text in it The text hides either from top or bottom.
I have tried all the solution but in vain..Kindly help me!

when I set fixed height the long text hides from top and bottom and when I put height as wrap-content the text hides from bottom.
As there is a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of activity I am not able to set this edit text to get Long Text. 
The whole code is given below. I have to upload whole code to understand better.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TextNotes"
    android:id="@+id/drawerText">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/logoColor"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:background="#FAFAFA"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:id="@+id/toolbars">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="All Notes"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/logoColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:fontFamily="@font/cour"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toolbar_button_text"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_button_text"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="-7dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tick_green" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbars"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollV"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:hint="Note Title"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/cour"
                    android:paddingStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbars"/>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_below="@+id/edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgBook"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_book"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner"
                        android:layout_width="230dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgBook"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
                        android:padding="2dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtChk"
                        android:text="Saved"
                        android:visibility="invisible"/>


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
                        android:layout_width="23dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_about_grey"
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgReminderTxt"
                        android:layout_width="23dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgAbout"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_reminder" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/line"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout"
                    android:background="@color/grey"/>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtRecycler"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_below="@id/line"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imgRecycler"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txtRecycler"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/TodoRecycler"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imgRecycler"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <TextView
    android:id="@+id/charcTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wordsTxt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    />
//Below is the description edit text that I want to make scrollable
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/text_write"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/TodoRecycler"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/calibri"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:hint="What is on your mind?"
                        android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                        android:paddingStart="15dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
//Used below lines to make edit text scrollable but no success
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                        android:overScrollMode="always"
                        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                        android:foregroundGravity="top"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:isScrollContainer="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horSview"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_scroll"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bold"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_bold_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/italic"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_italic_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/underline"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_underline_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/strike"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_strike_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/highlight"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_a_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bullet"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_bullet_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bulletNumber"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_bullet_one_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/toDoList"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_list_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/leftIndent"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_indent_right_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/RightIndent"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_indent_left_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/moveBottom"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_align_bottom_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/moveTop"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_align_top_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/moveto"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_list_white"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_scroll"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_scroll_right"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_right_green"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_scroll2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll_left"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_scroll_left"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_scroll_left_green"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_text"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/text_drawer_menu"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want that whenever I put long text it should scroll and the whole text should be shown (from top and bottom) above bottom horizontal scroll bar.
Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnlSP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qQUQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The textview which you want to scroll, you should wrap a LinearLayout/Relativelayout around it and then wrap the LinearLayout/Relativelayout in to the scrollview. That should work.

Comment: The text is not hiding from bottom but from top it hides :(

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots at the end of my post. Kindly have a look at it and assist me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set fix height of edit text and then use below code for scrolling:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit);
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.edit) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
        }
       }
       return false;
    }
 });
```